# How to disable/hide the VsCode logo from the Title bar ( upper left corner )?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

is there a way to hide/disable it ?

Comment: find a black postit and stick it to the monitor, or find the logo svg in the executable and replace it with an empty svg of the same size

Answer (score 0):

You can go fullscreen, or drag out the Editors and the Solution Explorer and have those in a separate window

Comment: VSC does not have a **Solution Explorer**. That is VS.